# How to run jBoss AS 7 with eclipse 3.6(helios)?

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, jboss7.x

For some reason, I need to upgrade my JBOSS server to JBOSS AS 7, but I found that that default latest adapter is just for AS 5. Any Suggestions?

Right now I'm using JBOSS AS 4.2 and eclipse 3.6(helios), after a quick search I find I can either upgrade both my eclipse to 3.7 indigos and JBOSS 7, or I can use eclipse 3.6 with JBOSS 6. Since I have plugins on my current IDE, install a new eclipse isn't my first choice, then how can I run JBOSS 7 with eclipse 3.6?

Thank you.

Yao

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Download the "Development" version of JBoss tools, which includes the latest Jboss AS Adapter for JBoss 7, by pasting this URL into Exclipse --> Help menu --> install new software:

http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/development/indigo/

Comment: ... and the checkbox for the adapters is under "JBoss Web and Java EE Development" -> "JBossAS Tools".